# Calling a method from an existing instance

Tags: android, python, python-2.7, kivy

My understanding of Object Orientated Programming is a little shaky so if you have any links that would help explain the concepts it would be great to see them!

I've shortened the code somewhat.  The basic principle is that I have a game that starts with an instance of the main Controller class.  When the game is opened the Popup class is opened. The events happens as follows:

1. The start button on the popup is clicked
2. The method start_click() runs
3. Which calls the method start_game() in the Controller instance
4. Which in turn changes the game state to 'True' in the original Controller instance

My problem is with step 3.  The error message I get is:

```
TypeError: unbound method start_game() must be called with Controller 
instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

I guess there needs to be some reference to the Controller class in the StartPopUp class.  But I don't quite understand how to create that reference?

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.8.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, NumericProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<StartPopUp>            
    size_hint: .2, .2
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: 'Welcome'
    Button:
        text: 'Play'
        on_press: root.start_click()
        on_press: root.dismiss()

''')

class StartPopUp(Popup):

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(StartPopUp, self).__init__(**kw)

    def start_click(self):
        Controller.start_game()                    

class Controller(Widget):
    playing_label = BooleanProperty(False)          #Intitial phase of game is off

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(Controller, self).__init__(**kw)        

    def start_popup(self, dt):    
        sp = StartPopUp()
        sp.open()

    def start_game(self):
        self.playing_label = True
        print self.playing_label   

class MoleHuntApp(App):

    def build(self):
        game = Controller()
        Clock.schedule_once(game.start_popup, 1)
        return game

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MoleHuntApp().run()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the instance like this

```
class StartPopUp(Popup):

    def __init__(self, controller, **kw):
        super(StartPopUp, self).__init__(**kw)
        self.controller = controller

    def start_click(self):
        self.controller.start_game()
```

and in Controller

```
def start_popup(self, dt):    
    sp = StartPopUp(self)
    sp.open()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `start_game()` on an instance of the `Controller` class. For example,

```
def start_click(self):
    controller = Controller()
    controller.start_game()
```

This way, `startgame()`'s `self` argument will be pointing to the `controller` object. But you then need to keep track of the created `Controller` instance to be able to later modify it again. In which case there is no reason to have `playing_label` as a static variable.

What you probably want to have is a static method that can just be called without having to have an instance of the `Controller` class. For that, you can make `start_game()` a static method using the [`staticmethod` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#staticmethod) like so:

```
@staticmethod
def start_game():
    Controller.playing_label = True
    print Controller.playing_label
```

Then, you can continue using `Controller.start_game()`.

Comment: I tried the staticdecorator part of your method which worked great! but I don't quite understand it.  Hypothetically say you have two instances of controller, if you call the static method, is the method being run, and the playing_label being updated in both instances of controller?

Comment: Yes, static method and static variables are not per-instance. So, "the `playing_label` being updated in both instances of controller" is technically not correct. Because of where you've defined `playing_label`, there is only one value of it for all the instances of `controller` created.

Answer (score 1):

As is obvious from the error message the method `start_game()` must be called for a particular instance of the controller class. You could add an `getInstance()` method for the controller class which returns the current active instance of the controller. Call this from inside the `start_click()` method before calling the `start_game()`. Say it returns `instanceC`. Then you can call `start_game()` method as `instanceC.start_game()` from the `start_click()`.

Comment: I think this method was a little over my head, I attempted it but couldn't get it to work, hopefully i'll come back to it once i've learnt a little more about OOP!

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the game object in the moment that you create the StartPopUp object and make the StartPopUp to keep a reference to it, so you can use this instance later for the start_click() method, like this:

```
class StartPopUp(Popup):

    def __init__(self, game_ctrl, **kw):
        super(StartPopUp, self).__init__(**kw)
        self.game_ctrl = game_ctrl

    def start_click(self):
        self.game_ctrl.start_game()                    

class Controller(Widget):
    playing_label = BooleanProperty(False)          #Intitial phase of game is off

    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(Controller, self).__init__(**kw)        

    def start_popup(self, dt):    
        sp = StartPopUp(self)
        sp.open()

    def start_game(self):
        self.playing_label = True
        print self.playing_label
```