# Kivy: Update widgets in a class from outside?

Tags: android, python, kivy

It seems like this should be easy but I have been trying for a week (really) to update a column of buttons in a class (called from a popup)

If you run the code below, select the top button, and select "done" on the popup, the top button is never removed, the function is called though

**The Problem:**

Every time I call function `refreshList` in class `MyWidget` from class `JobDialog`, I can see that the function is running, but I think it opens up a new instance and I cannot see what it builds! This should be simple it seems. I am just not getting anywhere by writing more spaghetti!

Any input? Do I have to define something in the APP class?

Thank you for you time!

Here is the code I have (super-simplified):

```
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage, Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label


Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', '0') #Force Fullscreen off.

#setting up default variables
loggedInUserName = "default usrname"
isLoggedIn = 0

currentProdNum = ""

ResultSet = {
    "1231" : {"name" : "test text asdf", "dateDue" : "", "status" : "0"},

}


Builder.load_string("""

<MyWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        ScrollView:
            size_hint_x: 500
            do_scroll_x: False
            BoxLayout:
                id: resultScrollList
                cols: 1
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height

""")

class menuScreen(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(menuScreen,self).__init__(**kwargs)
    pass




class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    login = ObjectProperty()
    def refreshList(self, *kwargs):
        #for the scrollList::
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
        # Make sure the height is such that there is something to scroll.
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))

        self.orientation = "vertical"

        self.name_input = TextInput(text='name')

        #self.add_widget(self.name_input)

        self.login_button = Button(text="login")
        self.login_button.bind(on_press=self.login)

        self.job_popup = JobDialog(self) # initiation of the popup, and self gets passed

        #self.add_widget(self.login_button)

        #start adding widgets:

        for key, value in ResultSet.items():
            #first create the string for the box:
            if value["status"] == "0":
                print(key)
                l = Label(text='Hello world', font_size='20sp')
                strstr = value['name'] + ' - ' + value['dateDue'] + ' - ' + value['status']
                btn = Button(text=strstr,id=key, size_hint_y=None)
                btn.bind(on_press=self.login)
                layout.add_widget(btn)
                pass
            pass

        self.ids.resultScrollList.clear_widgets()
        #self.ids.resultScrollList.add_widget(layout)
        #root.parent.MyWidget.ids.resultScrollList.add_widget(layout)

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyWidget,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        #for the scrollList::
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
        # Make sure the height is such that there is something to scroll.
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))

        self.orientation = "vertical"

        self.name_input = TextInput(text='name')

        #self.add_widget(self.name_input)

        self.login_button = Button(text="login")
        self.login_button.bind(on_press=self.login)

        self.job_popup = JobDialog(self) # initiation of the popup, and self gets passed

        #self.add_widget(self.login_button)

        #start adding widgets:

        for key, value in ResultSet.items():
            #first create the string for the box:
            print(key)
            if value["status"] == "0":
                l = Label(text='Hello world', font_size='20sp')
                strstr = value['name'] + ' - ' + value['dateDue'] + ' - ' + value['status']
                btn = Button(text=strstr,id=key, size_hint_y=None)
                btn.bind(on_press=self.login)
                layout.add_widget(btn)
                pass
            pass

        self.ids.resultScrollList.clear_widgets()
        self.ids.resultScrollList.add_widget(layout)

    def login(self, instance):
        global isLoggedIn
        global currentProdNum
        currentProdNum = instance.id
        print("current Prod to modify is %s" % currentProdNum)
        self.job_popup.open()
    pass


class JobDialog(Popup):
    global currentProdNum
    print("current Prod to modify is %s" % str(currentProdNum) )
    tempTitle = loggedInUserName
    title = tempTitle
    def __init__(self,my_widget,**kwargs):  # my_widget is now the object where popup was called from.
        super(JobDialog,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        #my_widget.title='Authenticate'
        self.my_widget = my_widget
        #title='Authenticate', size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400)
        self.content = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        self.title = "this is a test"
        aimg = AsyncImage(source='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/Test.png')

        self.done_button = Button(text='Done')
        self.done_button.bind(on_press=self.DoneAction)

        self.cancel_button = Button(text='Cancel')
        self.cancel_button.bind(on_press=self.cancel)

        self.pass_input = TextInput(text='')

        self.content.add_widget(aimg)
        self.content.add_widget(self.done_button)
        self.content.add_widget(self.cancel_button)


    def DoneAction(self,*args):
        global loginLookupTable
        global loggedInName
        print(" %s selected!" % self.done_button.text) # and you can access all of its attributes
        print("State of Prod:")
        print(ResultSet[currentProdNum]['status'])
        ResultSet[currentProdNum]['status'] = 1
        print('Changed to 1.')
        self.dismiss()
        app = App.get_running_app()
        app.mywidget.refreshList()

    def cancel(self,*args):
        print("cancel")
        self.dismiss()

class MyApp(App):
    mywidget = MyWidget()
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()


MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Can you make a simple runnable example that contains only your problem?

Comment: OK, simplified. Better?

Comment: you never remove the top button in your refreshList method

Comment: True. That's not the problem... This is helping me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23994233/calling-a-method-from-an-existing-instance and I think I'm almost there!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured it out!
It is very hard to program with classes when you don't understand how they work. Instead of calling `app.my_widget.refreshList()` (which worked because I defined it in the App class) , I made called `self.my_widget.refreshList()` once I had defined it above to inherit "self" from the other class! Sounds simple. Here is the working code for those who are interested:

```
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage, Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label


Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', '0') #Force Fullscreen off.

#setting up default variables
loggedInUserName = "default usrname"
isLoggedIn = 0

currentProdNum = ""

ResultSet = {
    "1231" : {"name" : "test text asdf", "dateDue" : "", "status" : "0"},

}


Builder.load_string("""

<MyWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        ScrollView:
            size_hint_x: 500
            do_scroll_x: False
            BoxLayout:
                id: resultScrollList
                cols: 1
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height

""")

class menuScreen(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(menuScreen,self).__init__(**kwargs)
    pass




class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    login = ObjectProperty()
    def refreshList(self, *kwargs):
        #for the scrollList::
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
        # Make sure the height is such that there is something to scroll.
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))

        self.orientation = "vertical"

        self.name_input = TextInput(text='name')

        #self.add_widget(self.name_input)

        self.login_button = Button(text="login")
        self.login_button.bind(on_press=self.login)

        self.job_popup = JobDialog(self) # initiation of the popup, and self gets passed

        #self.add_widget(self.login_button)

        #start adding widgets:

        for key, value in ResultSet.items():
            #first create the string for the box:
            if value["status"] == "0":
                print(key)
                l = Label(text='Hello world', font_size='20sp')
                strstr = value['name'] + ' - ' + value['dateDue'] + ' - ' + value['status']
                btn = Button(text=strstr,id=key, size_hint_y=None)
                btn.bind(on_press=self.login)
                layout.add_widget(btn)
                pass
            pass

        self.ids.resultScrollList.clear_widgets()
        #self.ids.resultScrollList.add_widget(layout)
        #root.parent.MyWidget.ids.resultScrollList.add_widget(layout)

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MyWidget,self).__init__(**kwargs)

        #for the scrollList::
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
        # Make sure the height is such that there is something to scroll.
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))

        self.orientation = "vertical"

        self.name_input = TextInput(text='name')

        #self.add_widget(self.name_input)

        self.login_button = Button(text="login")
        self.login_button.bind(on_press=self.login)

        self.job_popup = JobDialog(self) # initiation of the popup, and self gets passed

        #self.add_widget(self.login_button)

        #start adding widgets:

        for key, value in ResultSet.items():
            #first create the string for the box:
            print(key)
            if value["status"] == "0":
                l = Label(text='Hello world', font_size='20sp')
                strstr = value['name'] + ' - ' + value['dateDue'] + ' - ' + value['status']
                btn = Button(text=strstr,id=key, size_hint_y=None)
                btn.bind(on_press=self.login)
                layout.add_widget(btn)
                pass
            pass

        self.ids.resultScrollList.clear_widgets()
        self.ids.resultScrollList.add_widget(layout)

    def login(self, instance):
        global isLoggedIn
        global currentProdNum
        currentProdNum = instance.id
        print("current Prod to modify is %s" % currentProdNum)
        self.job_popup.open()
    pass


class JobDialog(Popup):
    global currentProdNum
    print("current Prod to modify is %s" % str(currentProdNum) )
    tempTitle = loggedInUserName
    title = tempTitle
    def __init__(self,my_widget,**kwargs):  # my_widget is now the object where popup was called from.
        super(JobDialog,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        #my_widget.title='Authenticate'
        self.my_widget = my_widget
        #title='Authenticate', size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400)
        self.content = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
        self.title = "this is a test"
        aimg = AsyncImage(source='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/Test.png')

        self.done_button = Button(text='Done')
        self.done_button.bind(on_press=self.DoneAction)

        self.cancel_button = Button(text='Cancel')
        self.cancel_button.bind(on_press=self.cancel)

        self.pass_input = TextInput(text='')

        self.content.add_widget(aimg)
        self.content.add_widget(self.done_button)
        self.content.add_widget(self.cancel_button)


    def DoneAction(self,*args):
        global loginLookupTable
        global loggedInName
        print(" %s selected!" % self.done_button.text) # and you can access all of its attributes
        print("State of Prod:")
        print(ResultSet[currentProdNum]['status'])
        ResultSet[currentProdNum]['status'] = 1
        print('Changed to 1.')
        self.dismiss()
        self.my_widget.refreshList()

    def cancel(self,*args):
        print("cancel")
        self.dismiss()

class MyApp(App):
    mywidget = MyWidget()
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()


MyApp().run()
```